# Win7 Show a window if computer idle

Tags: windows-7, alt-tab

Is there a script, third party app or scheduleable task I could use to ALT&TAB to a specific window if the computer is idle for a pre-defined time?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows 7's built in Task Scheduler to launch a program upon being idle. Search for "task scheduler" in the start menu and go to Action - Create Task... - Triggers - New - On idle.
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Sounds great! But can that be used to alt&tab to an already open (for example) Opera browser window?